# Regex expression formulation

Tags: c#, regex, expression

Guys I do not know how to exactly formulate regex expressions(I have never learnt it),However for the situation I am in right now I know its a regex expression that I need to use.

I need to allow the following

```
$ANYTHNG_HERE$+(5*8-7) //in short a word between dollar sign and any mathematical operator(s)
```

And I strictly need to avoid things like

```
&ANYTHNG_HERE&+6fdfd(5+6)
```

How do I proceed ?

Comment: is there any specific characters which you would like to avoid ?

Comment: @SpiderCode , no but i want to avoid combinations of numbers and alphabets (1ytfdf etc is NOT allowed)

Answer (score 1):

You can match the math equation with:

`\([0-9*+/-]*\)`

and you can match the beginning of the line with:

`^\$`

So just add a dot in the middle and here's the full regex:

`^\$.*?\([0-9*+/-]*\)`

Comment: Are you aware that your character class also matches `,` and `.`?

Comment: Oops! I had no idea that you could do that with symbols and dashes. Edited the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but this:

`^\$.*\$\+([\(\)\d*-\\]+)$`

Will match:

`$ANYTHNG_HERE$+(5*8\7)`

But not

`&ANYTHNG_HERE&+6fdfd(5+6)`

If you need further revisions, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

What about `\$.*\$[-+*/()0-9]*$` ?

Be warned: this is a regex for sed - I have NEVER used C# !

I have checked it against MSDN though, and it seems to check out.

Comment: You missed `^` at the beginning..Also it seems like he need's `+` in between $ and expression